# Coding Bat wrong, or is my code wrong?

Tags: python

I have been doing practice over at CodingBat, and i am stuck on the Logic-1 > alarm_clock question. This is my code

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
  if 0 < day < 6 and not vacation:
    return "7:00"
  elif day == 0 or day == 6 and not vacation:
    return "10:00"
  elif day == 6 or day == 0 and vacation:
    return "off"
  else:
    return "10:00"
```

However, the website tells me that my code is incorrect.
  [This is the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnhge.png)

Comment: By the way, instead of posting a screenshot of the website, post a link to the website—and, more importantly, enough of a description that people can understand what your problem is even without following the link. See [mcve] in the help.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is here (and repeated the next clause):

```
elif day == 0 or day == 6 and not vacation:
```

In Python (following most earlier computer languages) `and` has higher precedence than `or`. In the same way that `2 + 3 * 5` means `2 + (3*5)` and not `(2+3) * 5`, your code doesn't mean `(day==0 or day==6) and not vacation`, it means `day==0 or (day==6 and not vacation)`.

To fix this, just add the explicit parentheses (on both clauses).

---

But notice that you've got `day == 0 or day == 6` on one line, and `day == 6 or day == 0` on the other, but these are actually the same condition. So you can simplify this a bit:

```
elif day == 0 or day == 6:
    if not vacation:
        return "10:00"
    els:
        return "off"
```

… and then the problem doesn't even come up.